# NameError in Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmTVV.png): `undefined local variable or method`sessions_path' for #<#:0x2db44c8>`when I go to`localhost:3000/login` which isn't making much sense to me seeing the code is exactly like that of a previous application where it does work.

Here are the code of the related files.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => 'register'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout' 

resources :users, :path => '/'

root :to => 'users#index' 
match '/:id' => 'users#show'
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged in!'
    else
        flash.now.alert = 'Invalid email or password'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged out!'
end
end
```

**views/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
<div class="field"></div>
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
</div>
<div class="field"></div>
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= text_field_tag :password %>
</div>
<div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log in"%></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does the full error say? "NameError" isn't helpful but at least the stacktrace could provide helpful context for what is going wrong.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the code and a screenshot of the entire error description.

Comment: try adding resources :sessions to your routes

Comment: lol that pretty much fixed it! Add an answer so I can approve your answer to close this question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have a `sessions_path` defined - use `rake routes` to verify. To use the `sessions_path` method, you will need to have `resources :sessions` in your routes specification.

Pertaining to your `SessionsController`, your routes file should look like...

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:create]
get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => 'register'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout' 

resources :users, :path => '/'

root :to => 'users#index' 
match '/:id' => 'users#show'
```

Comment: Edited: only create action was missing

Comment: Yep, Peter Andersen solved it above, I told him to answer so he could get the points but oh well :P

Comment: Why "resources" ? as far as in case of session we never deal with a series of sessions at once and we never list sessions in an index or anything like that?

Comment: `resource sessions` could work too. but then you would have to be conscious of the pluralization whenever using `session_path` as opposed to `sessions_path` which has grown to be the norm